# UITextField onText Changed

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitextfield

I need to survey a textField's value every time it's changed. To handle this, I simply added that action to the .h file and implemented that method in the .m file. (That is, I "ctrl+click"ed the "Value Changed" event from the Storyboard and dragged it onto my .h file). Even if I just try to NSLog from the method, it's not logging anything, whether the value of my textbox is changed or not.

My header file includes the following:

```
(IBAction)changed:(UITextField *)sender;
```

and my .m file has the following:

```
 (IBAction)changed:(UITextField *)sender {

NSLog(@"%@", @"Changed");

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make one of your controllers the text field's delegate and implement [`textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006991-CH3-SW9)

Answer (score 3):

Just try "Editing Changed" instead of "Value Changed".

Answer (score 1):

You can use the notification name `UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification` to listen the text did changed event:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                       selector:@selector(_yourTextFieldDidChangedMethod:)
                                           name:UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification
                                         object:self.yourTextField];
```

and the selector:

```
- (void)_yourTextFieldDidChangedMethod:(NSNotification *)notification {
   // do your work here
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. @Josh Caswell's answer worked, though.